Use of C1D, US visa for tourism purpose in the USA
I'm an Indian seafarer possessing a valid US visa (C1/D). I wanted to know if I can use the same along with my Indian passport to visit the United States of America for a week as a tourist?

You’ll need a visitor visa for a holiday that’s completely unconnected to a work trip using your C1/D visa https://uk.usembassy.gov/visas/temporary-employment/air-and-sea-crew-members/

A C-1/D visa allows you to be admitted to the US in C-1 or D status.  C-1 status is transit.  If your purpose in entering the US is anything other than to get somewhere else, you don't qualify for C-1 status.  D status is as a crew member working aboard a vessel or aircraft.  To qualify for D status. You must "intend[] to land temporarily and solely in pursuit of [your] calling as a crewman," which is a criterion that you will not fulfill when you arrive with the intention of visiting as a tourist.
The answer to your question, therefore, is no. To visit the US as a tourist, you need to be able to enter in B-2 status, which means that you need a B-2 visa or a combination B-1/B-2 visa.
(This answer ignores the Visa Waiver Program and ESTA because Indian citizens are not eligible to participate.)
